# Target 2TB NVME SSD same size as 1TB source after cloning

Tags: windows-10, ssd, clone, disk-cloning

I've just done an offline clone of a 1TB NVMe SSD to a 2TB NVMe SSD (I tried software cloning a few times but I always had issues booting to windows). Whilst the clone does boot, it shows the exact same size as the original source disk, meaning 1TB of storage is missing, and not in unallocated.

[image: Disk Management Screenshot]

To be clear, I have also tried shrinking the volume already and I'm afraid that didn't work, nor did extend without parameters in diskpart

Comment: Try to see if [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) can see the missing space. If it can, use it to extend the disk.

Comment: This is a common “gotcha” many people run into. This is because you cloned the partition which is 1TB from the source to the destination. If you want to make full use of space you can either copy the data using a tool that does file copying — not partition cloning — or see about reclaiming the lost space.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 actually if what he did was a partition clone, he should be able to extend it out-of-the-box. The real reason is, what he did was a *full-disk* clone, i.e. partition table included, **AND** the fact that the partition table is GPT, which will have the backup copy at the end of the disk. In order to "reclaim" the space, the backup GPT will need to be relocated to the "new end". I don't know if `gdisk` fixes it automatically but you can at least do a backup->zap->reload cycle manually with `sgdisk`, which could *possibly* fixes the problem (I never actually tried).

Comment: Btw if you dare to do that online in Windows, you'll likely need to reboot the see the effect. (If it allows you to and doesn't crash like in Linux)